# What do you think is the best choice? choose (a/b) / (1/2/3) - related to Usage of Unlike

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's a sentence I've made.

When I was a third grader in college, I participated in a contest.

> A. Unlike most of the students who had been working on the project for more than a month,
>
> B. Unlike most of the students, who had been working on the project for more than a month, (comma added)

.

> 1. I had just a few days fot the contest.
> 2. I had only a few days for the contest.
> 3. I just had a few days for the contest.
> 4. I only had a few days for the contest.

So I worked on the project extra hard in the days leading up to it.

Comment: The main clause in your sentence is clear enough that you don't need to worry whether lack of punctuation creates ambiguity.  But a rule of thumb: never rely upon punctuation alone to disambiguate a statement. If a mere comma makes an important difference in the meaning of a sentence, rephrase the *$*%*@# sentence.

Comment: Adding the comma is exactly what is needed. There is no need to rephrase anything.

Comment: On a side note, 지훈씨, we don't refer to our years in college as "grades." We would say, "When I was a junior in college...," (assuming it is a four-year college) or, "(When I was) in my third year of college...".

Comment: @pyobum 고마워요~!^^

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's take A & B first.

In (B.), you are disassociating the students from who they actually were

> who had been working on the project

when you are using a comma between *the students* and *who had been working on the project*

So (A.) is right.

> A. Unlike most of the students who had been working on the project for more than a month,

Next, let's get on with 1,2,3 & 4.
Here ***just*** and ***only*** when used before ***had*** will completely change the meaning of the sentence.

As in,

> I just had a few days for the contest.

In the above, ***just*** plays the role of an *Adverb of Time* and it means *just a while back*.

> I only had a few days for the contest.

The above says that *you and only only yourself* have a few days for something.

So using either 1 or 2 will get to mean what you actually want to.